# Check if url matches in template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to check in template that some url match any pattern from urls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is something you'd normally want to do in a views.py file with the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse)() helper for named URLs with known args or [resolve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve)() for paths.

If you do need this functionality in a template specifically, here is a hacky solution:

```
@register.simple_tag
def urlpath_exists(path):
    """Returns True for successful resolves()'s."""
    try:
        return bool(resolve(path))
    except Resolver404:
        return False
```

**Note**: this doesn't guarantee that the URL is valid, just that there was a pattern match.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the "as" form of the url tag to check if a named URL exists.

```
{% url path.to.view as the_url %}
{% if the_url %}
  <a href="{{ the_url }}">Link to optional stuff</a>
{% endif %}
```

When "as" is used it does not raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there is not simple method to do this. So I wrote a simple templatetag which takes url name and call reverse method for it and put reverse into try..except:

```
try:
    result = reverse(url)
except:
    result = None
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your project name is dummy. Then,

```
from dummy.urls import urlpatterns
def find_url(url):
  for e in urlpatterns:
    if e.regex.match(url):
      print 'found!'  #or do whatever you want
      return          #then exit the procedure.
  print 'not found!'
```